# What does this do in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I came across the function below in one of the SharePoint system javascript files.

```
function RTE_InsertImage(strBaseElementID)
{ULS1Lu:;
   //A bunch of javascript
}
```

I have never seen something like `ULS1Lu:;` in any of the javascript code I have worked with before.  Does anyone know what this is doing?

Sorry the weak title on the question.  I wasn't sure how else to phrase it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is using label's in JavaScript bad practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906762/is-using-labels-in-javascript-bad-practice)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Its a [code label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label), technically they don't need the semicolon, but in javascript it shouldn't hurt. The label will allow a break or continue statement to jump the code back to it.

Most people consider that instead of labels it is better to use function calls whenever possible.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like they are just creating a Label. Possibly, as a marker or for some infamous use. Of course such labels owe a large part of their fame to [goto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46586/goto-still-considered-harmful) statements.